# Android : cannot read image in assets folder and assign to imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I have a file `food.jpg` in assets folder. I have try many ways. but I still cannot get this image into imageView. when run, instead of display image "food.jpg", it displays image that I have declared in xml file. (that image is in drawable folder).

The first way is:

```
int asset_id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("food", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(asset_id);
```

The second way is:

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream istr;
try {
         istr = assetManager.open("food");
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 istr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please teach me how to fix this problem.

thanks :)

Comment: You tried to replace assetManager.open('food') with assetManager.open('food.jpg') ?

Comment: @secretlm after I change from food to food.jpg. my problem will be terminated :(

Comment: @hqt what do you mean by that? can't you replace food with food.jpg?

Comment: @user1566160 when i run, the app will appear error: "unfortunately, myapp has stopped". if I change from food.jpg to food. no error. but cannot display image :(

Comment: @hqt What is the log cat when this error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. just add image MIME-Type`(.jpg,jpeg,.png... etc)` in below line:

```
istr = assetManager.open("ceo.jpg");
```

full code for your refrance

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open("ceo.jpg");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            istr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code...

```
try {
        // get input stream
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("food.jpg");
        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        // set image to ImageView
        imgNews.setImageDrawable(d);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i run, the app will appear error: "unfortunately, myapp has stopped". if I change from food.jpg to food. no error. but cannot display image :(